# How to Convert String Reference values to string in zend Amf Php?

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework, zend-amf

I am using Zend Frame work in my project. A Client side Flex Application sending the data to server using Remote Object as Amf - Php and i Use Charles web debugging proxy to Monitoring the data. Zend cannot recognizing the String reference values.

Example two fields can have the same string value

```
$variable1 = 'selva' 
$variable2 = 'selva'
```

Both the values are string and are same text , now AMF converts the second value to string reference (watched in charles) that is the actual data i am receiving has the reference of the first variable.

EG:- For the above case

```
$variable1 = 'selva'
$variable2 = 'variable1'
```

Second variable take first variable reference or variable name.
How can I resolve this ?
Thanks in Advance.